# How can I let my clients export BigQuery query results as CSV

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

So I have developed a backend API in java on Google App Engine. The API is used to return real time stats by running queries on BigQuery.

I have also developed Front End in AngularJS which communicates with the backend API and allows users to login, and view aggregated stats.

I would like to let my users export data as CSV from BigQuery (directly through my front end application).

I'm not sure what's the best way to achieve that. Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I should mention, I need a solution that scales. Exporting to GCS is limited to 1000 exports per day so I'm not liking that option much. Also, data I would like my users to export might include up to millions of records.

Answer (score 3):

I could see you doing this one of two ways, depending on your needs:

1. Run an [export job to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/exporting-data-from-bigquery) in CSV format, then download the exported CSV from GCS.
2. Read data from [tabledata.list API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list), converting the fv format into CSV on your server and creating a downloadable CSV file.

I'd probably recommend the first option.  Export jobs are likely to scale better, since they are generally more performant for large tables than repeated calls to tabledata.list.  It also avoids the need to write custom code to convert your data to CSV.

Comment: Actually we too need an alternative to this as it takes too long. The query takes 2 minutes, but exporting 100 rows takes again 1-2 minutes. This ends up in 3-4 minutes, which is way too long, and was requested to improve it. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: As with most operations in BigQuery, export jobs are not optimized for small numbers of rows.  There is work underway to improve the speed of export jobs but it's in early stages and I can't provide an ETA.  Given the current BigQuery system, the suggestions above are the best I can think of.  In your case, with just 100 rows, performance would probably be better using tabledata.list.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting to GCS is currently our scaled solution, maybe you can contact the team to have some special quota for you. tabledata.list returning direct CSV output is about to be deprecated, an alternative is using bq cli's head command with --format=csv, but that is not a solution for scale.